# How to access custom class properties as a referenced outlet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a view that has a reference outlet to a UIViewController called `theView`. This view uses a custom class which has a property named `theStr`. I can access theView from the UIViewController like: `self.theView`, however, I can not access the custom class properties like : `self.theView.theStr` I get error: `Property 'theStr' not found on object of type 'UIVIew *'`

Comment: who has a reference to whom? your view to the controller or the other way around or both? "the view *uses* a custom class" - what is that supposed to mean? does it inherit from that class or does your view hold an object of that class?

Comment: The controller has a reference to the view, the view inherits from UIView.

Comment: and where does your *custom class* come into play?

Comment: This view uses a custom class that inherits from UIView.

Comment: What do you mean by `uses`? Does it interhit from the custom class or in what way does it *use* it? Note: it **should** inherit!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the Interface Builder, select that view, and check Custom Class/Class section is correct in Identity Inspector.

Also, to access it's properties, you will need to include header file of custom class

Comment: Might be true, but where from do you take the information this has anything to do with storyboards!?

Comment: it might not storyboard but Interface Builder.

Comment: still no indication of usage to be found

Comment: "I have a view that has a reference outlet to a UIViewController called theView" can be easily guess me that there's IB outlet used, also, if you don't think it is the case, post another answer please.

Comment: I do not like guessing around, therefore: NO, no answer until I know for sure what is wrong.

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The outlet type must be of the same custom type of the referenced object.
2. The custom class header must be imported.

Comment: Yes. When you set the custom class in identity inspector before connect it to referenced outlet, it will automatically set the custom type at outlet type, and can be easily avoid this situation

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have created custom view class and assigned it to the subview on the view of your view controller. I suppose that your custom view contains some element that you want to assign to the theStr property, but seems you have drag and dropped that instance to the view controller class. So right now your view controller has theStr `IBOutlet` property, but your custom view does not know about any theStr properties, because your custom view is a different object.

So you should think about your custom `UIView` object that you layout on your `UIViewController` view and add a property to your custom view instead of adding it to your view controller.

Just open your custom view class (.h file) and open your interface builder from where you can drag drop and assign theStr property in your custom view class.

Property 'theStr' not found on object of type 'UIVIew':

says that you really don't have any property with the theStr because seems you have assigned it not to a custom view but to view controller as I can suppose from your description.